# How to convert AIResponse gson to text that can be used on Text to Speech?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, text-to-speech

Hi I'm using the code from [Dialog Flow Example](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client)and I'm trying to customize the class AIButtonSampleActivity.

When I speak something and the app calls Dialog's Flow API, the AI response is being showed as a pop up and as JSON. I'm trying to convert that JSON or GSON to text and then to create a function text to speech.

How can I do that in this class?

```
    /**
 * Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package ai.api.sample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import ai.api.android.AIConfiguration;
import ai.api.android.GsonFactory;
import ai.api.model.AIError;
import ai.api.model.AIResponse;
import ai.api.model.Metadata;
import ai.api.model.Result;
import ai.api.model.Status;
import ai.api.ui.AIButton;

public class AIButtonSampleActivity extends BaseActivity implements AIButton.AIButtonListener {

    public static final String TAG = AIButtonSampleActivity.class.getName();

    private AIButton aiButton;
    private TextView resultTextView;

    private Gson gson = GsonFactory.getGson();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_aibutton_sample);

        resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
        aiButton = (AIButton) findViewById(R.id.micButton);

        final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration(Config.ACCESS_TOKEN,
                AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.PortugueseBrazil,
                AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);

        config.setRecognizerStartSound(getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.test_start));
        config.setRecognizerStopSound(getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.test_stop));
        config.setRecognizerCancelSound(getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.test_cancel));

        aiButton.initialize(config);
        aiButton.setResultsListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // use this method to disconnect from speech recognition service
        // Not destroying the SpeechRecognition object in onPause method would block other apps from using SpeechRecognition service
        aiButton.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // use this method to reinit connection to recognition service
        aiButton.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_aibutton_sample, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        final int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(AISettingsActivity.class);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(final AIResponse response) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult");

                resultTextView.setText(gson.toJson(response));

                Log.i(TAG, "Received success response");

                // this is example how to get different parts of result object
                final Status status = response.getStatus();
                Log.i(TAG, "Status code: " + status.getCode());
                Log.i(TAG, "Status type: " + status.getErrorType());

                final Result result = response.getResult();
                Log.i(TAG, "Resolved query: " + result.getResolvedQuery());

                Log.i(TAG, "Action: " + result.getAction());
                final String speech = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
                Log.i(TAG, "Speech: " + speech);
                TTS.speak(speech);

                final Metadata metadata = result.getMetadata();
                if (metadata != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Intent id: " + metadata.getIntentId());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Intent name: " + metadata.getIntentName());
                }

                final HashMap<String, JsonElement> params = result.getParameters();
                if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Parameters: ");
                    for (final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, String.format("%s: %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString()));
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(final AIError error) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onError");
                resultTextView.setText(error.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled");
                resultTextView.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    private void startActivity(Class<?> cls) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, cls);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is the response I recieve [image: Response from the API] and I'd like to get the parameter *{"messages":[{"speech":["Oi!"]}],"speech":"Oi!"},* and transform it into text to speech

Comment: can you show what the output is like, and expected output?

Comment: I've inserted it in the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `JSONObject` - [simple usage tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)

here replace `resultTextView.setText(gson.toJson(response));` in `onResult` with

```
JSONObject base = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(response));
String speechText = base.getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("fulfillment").getString("speech");
resultTextView.setText(speechText);
```